# Saving string to properties.settings

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Im creating a project in VS2010 using c#, I have a string value which im currently writting to the Properties.settings of the project.

I notcied sometime when shutting down my machine and restarting, that the value looks as though its not saving?

another possibility is that when im commiting my code to SVN that maybe that vallue aint been written.

So could someone please confirm for me,

when I write a string value to the Properties.Settings, is this only temporary? will I end up having to wrtie it to a text file or something instead?

Please and information regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advace ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are these Application-scope or User-scope? Application-scope settings cannot be changed at runtime.

Are you calling Settings.Save() to save the settings?

See this msdn article for more information:
[Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I am saving, just curous are these settings stored even if system is shutdown? wanted to be sure they are not just temporary as I need to store them for system restarts

Comment: They are most definitely permanent if you are saving them. You should be able to see the results in the config file that gets created. Application-scope settings are stored in a file which lives with the .exe. Since you are changing and saving at runtime these must be User-scope. User-scope settings get placed in a different location depending on which version of Windows you're on, but it's something like C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data. Even restarting Visual Studio will show you how the values persist.

Answer (score 0):

- The settings are stored in disc, although the path is hard to foretell, because .NET Framework manages it. An example of path where user-scope properties are saved:

d:\Users\Robo\AppData\Local\DataCrea\WorkShifts.exe_Url_4ssvgihryk04nltgkxam4dh4bdhymcqa\0.9.28.0\user.config

- The properties should be saved each time after command:

  Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
- I am not sure if following thing could affect your problem, but it's good to add boolean property CallUpgrade = True . Then add following lines into your main constructor:

  ```
      //upgrade properties, if version was increased
      if (Settings.Default.CallUpgrade)
      {
          Settings.Default.Upgrade();
          Settings.Default.CallUpgrade = false;
          Settings.Default.Save();
      }
  ```

... the Upgrade() will secure correct migration of settings from previous version.

Answer (score 0):

They are permanently saved if you call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Here is some code I use to remember the position and size of the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="my_namespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:my_namespace"
    Closing="save_position"
    Height="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Properties.Settings.Default}, Path=height, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Width="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Properties.Settings.Default}, Path=width, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Top="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Properties.Settings.Default}, Path=top, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Left="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Properties.Settings.Default}, Path=left, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

With this in the code behind:

```
private void save_position(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();            
}
```